# Line is not drawn to screen. Pyglet

Tags: python, graphics, pyglet

I thought a line would be drawn to the screen but I am having issues.
Keep in mind that this is a stripped version of my code so the unimportant bits don't get in the way of my problem.
Also I am very much a beginner so patience is appreciated :)

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window(800, 800)


class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def func(self):
        line1 = pyglet.shapes.Line(200, 200, 400, 400, width=1)
        return line1


inst = Test()


@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    line = inst.func()
    line.draw()


pyglet.app.run()
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. The program works fine for me.

Comment: @Rabbid76 So a line is being drawn from 200,200 to 400,400? If so that is very strange.

Comment: The problem seems to be related to your system.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there's nothing wrong with this code, I tried it on my main PC and it works fine, not sure what the issue with my laptop is.